# Is there a workaround to copy files to a vm?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to copy a file to a vm using [guestcontrol](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol) copyto. I have had a lot of trouble with the documentation which has not been fully updated with the changes in VirtualBox 5 and have also found that the [copy commands broke in VirtualBox 5](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14336).

It seems that there will be a fix in the next version, but is there a workaround to use until that time?

I can read a file to stdout using run + cat:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol 1-echo --username root --password root run /bin/cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

but I can't use stdin to write a file as it looks like the signal to close the stdin isn't forwarded to the guest (this creates the file and hangs without writing anything):

```
echo "Hello" | VBoxManage guestcontrol 1-echo --username root --password root run --no-wait-stdout /usr/bin/tee /test
```

Comment: Same problem with VirtualBox 5.0.24 r108355